# Why is this question (71065) closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[Star Wars trivia question to identify race](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71065/star-wars-trivia-question-help)

It's pretty clear what's being asked (Identify the species based on a fairly sufficient amount of information about it).

The answer apparently exists (according to one of the comments)

And it's not even a super-dumb trivial question *(Evidence: I have a SW Gold Badge and I didn't know the answer. Apparently neither did Richard).*

How's this question even remotely **"unclear what is being asked"**?

I'll grant you that the formatting/wording was crappy, but that doesn't even deserve a -4 votes - especially after a nice edit by Richard; never mind a close voting.

Comment: That's what I thought too.

Comment: Wasn't one of the closers, but one thing that struck me was that this felt less of a question than a *riddle*, and it wasn't even based in any sort of canon - there wasn't a "there's an alien in a hand in Ep. XII, what is it?", so there might not even *be* a right answer.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - how's a "riddle" phrased in that specific way NOT a valid question? And quiz questions like that are typically based on canon answers in my experience.

Comment: The main issue isn't with the riddleness, it's the fact that the OP doesn't know the answer to verify if a question is correct.
Regardless, I'd probably be fine with that question, but these are things that I noticed, and might have caused others to VtC.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - unlike a "Story ID" question, this one can be verified for correctness based on pretty unique set of properties listed (I'd agree with you if it was something like "lager bipedal humanoid of brown color" which is indeed impossible to validate due to too many canon options

Comment: True, but here we have an unknown quizmaster who we can't argue with or ask for clarifications. What it turns out there is no answer due to a bad phrasing if the question? Or multiple matches? These are usually the sort of questions we try to avoid.

Comment: It was pretty unclear **when asked**. It took me a while to puzzle out what he was driving it. I've asked for some further clarification

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan - If you read the answer posted, it should be clear not only that it's the correct answer, but that it also lists the source from which the original question was drawn from.

Comment: Yours truly had never even heard of the species in question until two days earlier - stumbled across them while on a *Wookieepedia* binge - and didn't know the correct answer, so you can add me to the list of *SW* Gold Badgers who didn't have a clue. It was a very good question. I hope he comes back with more like them, personally.

Answer (score 14):

In its original form, the question was quite poorly written. It wasn't immediately clear what the questioner was asking, nor was it apparent what was being asked and it was rightly closed as being "unclear":

> "Enter the name of an intelligent race , which is housed in a human
>   hand , can live many thousands of years and tell me what is her
>   talent"
>
> Well that's a question. Personally i couldn't find the correct answer.
>   Maybe you will be able.

After voting to close, I reflected on what was being asked and made some revisions to make the question clearer. I marked it as "reopen" and others followed suit. @GreenstoneWalker posted a comment with a potential answer (hat tip to him) and since he didn't seem inclined to follow up by posting an answer to the question, I've posted what appears to be the correct response along with some additional details.

All in all, this seems a text-book case of how SE is **supposed** to work;

- An inexperienced user posted a poorly written question.
- The community flagged it as unclear.
- A more experienced user edited the question.
- The question was marked for reopening.
- A user posted a comment with a potential source
- Another user did some additional research and turned that comment into an answer.